# Four-in-a-Row game

Tags: python, game, connect-four

I've made a working Four-in-a-Row game with grid lists and winning system. Both vertically and diagonally, is there some clear improvements to be made or common mistakes which could perhaps shorten it down? Is there any bad code or stupid logic which needs improving?

I haven't gotten to making the diagonal victory but have kept a few ideas in mind. Tips here would also be appreciated.

```
import os

gw = False

def cls():
    os.system('cls')
#Check vertical 4 in a row.
def check_ver():
    for row in range(6):
        xCounter = 0
        for col in range(5):
            if (grid[col][row] == "X"):
                xCounter += 1
        if xCounter == 4:
            xw()
    for row in range(6):
        oCounter = 0
        for col in range(5):
            if (grid[col][row] == "O"):
                oCounter += 1
        if oCounter == 4:
            ow()
#Check horizontal 4 in a row.
def check_hor():
    for col in range(5):
        xCounter = 0
        for row in range(6):
            if (grid[col][row] == "X"):
                xCounter += 1
            if xCounter == 4:
                xw()
    for col in range(5):
        oCounter = 0
        for row in range(6):
            if (grid[col][row] == "O"):
                oCounter += 1
            if oCounter == 4:
                xw()
#Checks all
def check_all():
    check_ver()
    check_hor()
#Checks for win, prints the game
def p():
    cls()
    check_all()
    for x in range(5):
        print(*grid[x], sep=" | ")
    for x in range(2):
        print(*info[x], sep=" | ")
#Empty prints for victory message
def em():
    for x in range(3):
        print("")
#Victory message and stuff for O
def ow():
    cls()
    em()
    print("O, Wins!".center(16))
    em()
    gw = True
#Victory message and stuff for X
def xw():
    cls()
    em()
    print("X, Wins!".center(16))
    em()
    gw = True
#Grid system
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]
info = [['==+===+===+===+===+=='],
        ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']]
#Game
while True:
    if gw == True:
        break
    else:
        p()
        row = int(input("X, column: "))
        row -= 1
        if 0 > row or row > 6:
            continue
        else:
            for x in range(4, -1, -1):
                if grid[x][row] == '.':
                    grid[x][row] = 'X'
                    break
        p()
        row = int(input("O, column: "))
        row -= 1
        if 0 > row or row > 6:
            continue
        else:
            for x in range(4, -1, -1):
                if grid[x][row] == '.':
                    grid[x][row] = 'O'
                    break
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/272068/revisions#rev-body-113e07f7-f869-41e1-b592-6480616b64c5) so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Stop repeating yourself**. You have a lot of repetitive code. A function to
check for horizontal win and a similar one for vertical win. Within each of
those functions, nearly identical blocks of code for X and then for O. And
within the main while-true loop, nearly identical blocks of code to get input
for player X and player O. None of that repetition is needed, some of it causes
bugs (eg, when X wins the program still asks for more input from O), and you'll
probably get good advice from others for eliminating a lot of it. I'm going to
focus on one topic: checking for wins.

**Checking one row is easy**. In these two-dimenional grid situations,
rows are typically the easy part, because the grid is naturally organized
row by row. So let's start with a simple function to determine whether
there is a win in a single row. We can use `itertools.groupby` to
organize the row into each player's contiguous sequences of cells.
Then we just find the longest sequence and return the player of that
sequence, provided that it is long enough:

```
from itertools import groupby

def collect_runs(row):
    # Takes a row. Yields all contiguous non-None sequences.
    for player, cells in groupby(row):
        if player:
            yield list(cells)

def check_row_win(row, win_size = 4):
    # Takes a row. Returns player of a winning run.
    runs = sorted(collect_runs(row), key = len)
    if not runs:
        return None
    long_run = runs[-1]
    player = long_run[0]
    return player if len(long_run) >= win_size else None
```

**Checking all rows is also easy**. With those building blocks in place,
we can check for horizontal wins by either player in one function -- in
other words, no need to repeat ourselves:

```
def check_horizontal_wins(grid):
    for row in grid:
        winner = check_row_win(row)
        if winner:
            return winner
    return None
```

**Use transpose to convert rows to columns**. Transposing a grid is easy in
Python. If we take our original grid and transpose it, we can use the same
row-checking logic to check for both horizontal and vertical wins:

```
def transpose(grid):
    return [list(tup) for tup in zip(*grid)]

def check_wins(grid):
    # Now it handles horizontal and vertical.
    for row in grid + transpose(grid):
        winner = check_row_win(row)
        if winner:
            return winner
    return None
```

**Use the same mindset to handle diagonal wins**. We've had good luck so far by
using a simple strategy: rather than repeating code or writing complex logic
for every case, we applied a fairly simple data transformation to re-use some
basic win-checking logic. With a little experimentation we can figure out a way
to convert diagonals to rows. For lack of a better term, I'll call the
transformation we need a grid *shift*:

```
# Consider a forward-diagonal win.

    . . . x .
    . . x . .
    . x . . .
    x . . . .

# A grid shift converts the diagonal to vertical, which we can handle.
# The process will include padding to fill in the empty quadrants.

    . . . x .
      . . x . .
        . x . . .
          x . . . .

# Now consider a backward-diagonal win.

    . o . . .
    . . o . .
    . . . o .
    . . . . o

# Reverse the rows and it becomes a forward-diagonal, which we can handle.

    . . . . o
    . . . o .
    . . o . .
    . o . . .
```

**Just use row-checking logic for everything**. Here is one way to implement the shift
transformation, along with the resulting function that can check for all types
of wins:

```
def shift(grid):
    return [
        padding(r) + row + padding(len(row) - r - 1)
        for r, row in enumerate(grid)
    ]

def padding(n):
    return [None for _ in range(n)]

def check_wins(grid):
    all_rows = (
        grid +                           # Horizontal
        transpose(grid) +                # Vertical
        transpose(shift(grid)) +         # Forward diagonal
        transpose(shift(reversed(grid))) # Backward diagonal
    )
    for row in all_rows:
        winner = check_row_win(row)
        if winner:
            return winner
    return None
```

Comment: Nice answer. Why have you made `collect_runs` separate to `check_row_win`? For example changing `collect_runs` to have `if player and len(cells) >= win_size: return player` instead.

Comment: @Peilonrayz Probably no good reason other than exposition and mostly habit. For many years I asked variants of this type of question during software engineering interviews and often in those questions we needed to know more about all of the runs than just whether there were 4 in a row. The OP should consider your suggestion seriously, because it is a good simplification.

Answer (score 2):

Also bear in mind that `os.system('cls')` is not platform independent.

Comment: For platform independency, use `os.system("cls" if os.name == "nt" else "clear")`.